# Adding/Removing fd's while epoll is blocked

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, epoll

I want to use a single thread to listen to incoming traffic from multiple sockets (some TCP, some UDP) and one or more pipes/FIFOs. These sockets/pipes need to be created/deleted dynamically. This requires me to modify the file descriptors used in epoll from multiple threads while it is blocked by the network event read thread. Is this allowed? Linux man page does not seem to give any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify parameters of already-running epoll().

However it is possible to force thread out of epoll() - e.g. by sending a signal - and re-enter epoll() with updated parameters.